# T-SQL QUERY , COUNT WITH TRAILER RECORD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

i have a code which starts with Alert procedure  and follows up with header , detail and trailer statements , where as i used select distinct for header , detail and in between both header and detail there is union command , so i was wondering if i could get the total number of records from header and detail in trailer row in specific column .. for now i have used

```
CONVERT(bigint, count(*) ) as Recordcount,
```

but it is displaying as 498 rows .. but we originally have 475 rows about trailer row . i think it is counting total number of sql query rows ..

Comment: MySQL isn't SQL Server, nor does it use SSMS or T-SQL. Know your RDBMS. :)

Comment: show us all your query, and, also `ASAP` ? really?

Comment: Not enough detail to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` does count the total number of rows in a dataset; including any rows that are completely made up of the value `NULL`. Take, for example:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(int,NULL) AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(int,NULL) AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(int,NULL) AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(int,NULL) AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(int,NULL) AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS N)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM VTE;
```

Notice this returns 6, not 1. If you wanted the value 1, then you'd need to use `COUNT(N)`.

Without sample data, this is pure guesswork, but i imagine you need to use `COUNT` with a `CASE` expression, to only include rows that aren't header or footers. This is pseudo-SQL, however, it'll be something like:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN <<Some expression that determines a row instead a header/footer>> THEN 1 END)
```

Also, there's no reason to use `CONVERT(BIGINT,COUNT(<<expr>>)`. If you're doing a count that might return more than `2^31-1` rows, then use `COUNT_BIG`. If you're not going to be returning more than `2^31-1` rows then just use `COUNT` (you're returning <500 rows, so literally no reason to use a `bigint`).